# In the film Tenet, why are some areas sealed?

Tags: tenet

In several scenes, doorways have a seal to prevent air flowing between them:

[image]

Why is this necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Protagonist (and some troops) are inside rooms sealed in with inverted air.

> INT. HOLD, ICEBREAKER – CONTINUOUS
>
> **Coming out of an AIRLOCK, he removes his respirator.** Walks
> past Wheeler drilling TENET SOLDIERS – non-inverted soldiers
> in respirators SPAR with inverted soldiers. Neil is amongst
> troops practising ‘LIFTING’ weapons from the floor.
>
> <sub><sup>[Tenet: Original Screenplay](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-T3zyGiaNczvSvASWD_T8WCcv3aMcGLG/view)</sup></sub>

It was explained earlier in the film that you can't breathe non-inverted air if you're inverted (and presumably vice-versa).

> WHEELER: **You need your own air – regular air won’t pass through the membranes
> of inverted lungs.** The number-one rule – don’t come into contact with your forwards self – that’s the whole point of these barriers –